# I created one master page which having header.In header section there are some links..i want to highlight that links without affecting master page

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net, web-applications

I am creating asp.net web application project.In that I created one master page which having header and footer.In header section there are some links..If i click the link That links goes to their own aspx file..that all aspx files are created by using the master page...how to highlight the every links when we go to that page without affecting the masterpage contents.

This is my code:(the line i put star  is the links)

```
<!-- header start -->

<li><a href="Default.aspx" class="Active">Home</a></li> *
          <li><a href="what.aspx">What We Do</a></li> *
          <li><a href="activities.aspx">Our Activities</a></li> *
          <li><a href="projects.aspx">Our Projects</a></li> * 
          <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li> *

<!-- header start -->
```

Comment: make a css class, for example an "active" class, like this: `.active a { background: #colorcode; ` and add it the the `li` element of the .aspx page you're actually visiting.

Answer (score 0):

Example you have pages: Home.aspx,WhatWeDo.aspx..
 Your Menu li0:Home.aspx,li1:WhatWeDo.aspx..
 You can use global javascript  in master page

`if(location.href.indexOf("Home.aspx")>0)setactivecss(0) 
 else if(location.href.indexOf("WhatWeDo.aspx")>0)setactivecss(1)`

to set active css for your select page
You can try your own code with my sugest.
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

**Idea1:** Add styles on the particular page with the reference of href link. For example in `what.aspx` you need to add it like below.

```
<style>
  li.a[href='what.aspx']{background-color:red; color:#fff;}
</style>
```

**Idea2:** Add classes for each `li`.

```
 <li class="default"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
 <li class="what"><a href="what.aspx">What We Do</a></li>
 <li class="activity"><a href="activities.aspx">Our Activities</a></li>
 <li class="projects"><a href="projects.aspx">Our Projects</a></li>
 <li class="Contact"><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
```

Apply the styles for the classes on that particular page. For exmaple in what.aspx you need to add it like below.

```
<style>
  li.what{background-color:red; color:#fff;}
</style>
```

Comment: <style>
  li.a[href='what.aspx']{background-color:red; color:#fff;}
</style>??where i have to copy this? in contentplaceholder1 of every page?

Comment: yes inside of each aspx page. But you need to change the page name in the style according to the original page.

Comment: i dont want this <style>...in my project i have css called .selected..how to add to to this???

Comment: i am not a asp.net developer

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with some jQuery

Add the id 'li-home' to your home link list item and give the list an id of 'menu'

```
<ul id='menu'>
  <li id="li-home"><a href="Default.aspx" class="Active">Home</a></li>
```

Then with jQuery

```
var path = window.location.pathname;

if (path.trim() == "/") {
    //covers the case of the default page since default.aspx will not show
    $("#li-home").addClass("Active");
}
else {
    var items = $("#menu li");
    items.each(function (index, li) {
         var menuitem = $(li);
         if (path.trim() !== "/" && path.indexOf(menuitem.find("a").attr("href")) > -1) {
             $("#li-home").removeClass("Active");
            menuitem.addClass("Active");
        }
    });
}
```